# The usage of the `using` statement in C# when dealing with Database related classes the best practice?

Tags: c#, database

The `using` statement automatically execute the Dispose method contained in IDisposable, database related classes (like SqlConnection, SqlCommand, etc) implement this interface.

So if I going to use this sort of classes should I use a `using` statement for the objects creation so the resources will be released at operation end?

For example, I need to use a SqlConnection, SqlCommand, SqlDataAdapter and a DataTable for some reason so I write this code below, is this the best way to do so or should I put the Dispose() at the finally clause of a try... catch... finally?

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString))
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
{
    // Do something...
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way you have it is correct. The Dispose() methods will automatically call Close(). That's not necessarily true for everything that implements IDisposable, but for the DB-related classes, it is.

Answer (score 3):

To complete *Chris* answer:

If you go the **try/finally** way you'll have to check if all the instances are not null:

```
try
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.ConnectionString);
    ...
}
finally
{
    if (con != null) con.Dispose();
    if (cmd != null) cmd...
}
```

The **using statement** is precisely made to simplify this kind of use-case.

By the way it can do much more cool things: http://pragmateek.com/c-scope-your-global-state-changes-with-idisposable-and-the-using-statement/

Comment: @Zignd: and this is true ... well ... my psychiatrist disagrees ... but I think he's crazy... ;)

Comment: "By the way it can do much more cool things:" -- Some of those don't seem to me to be good examples of `using`/`IDisposable`, as they *need* to be disposed of in *exactly* the reverse order of creation, or their attempts to restore state actually end up corrupting state.

Comment: Yes this is for this kind of use case: you have a bunch of code that plays with some global state because it needs a special environment to work (some culture, some Excel setting...) but you don't want to mess things up for code outside of this. So here the using scope is really a safeguard around specific code. But I get your point if you'd wrap some code that "legitimately" change the global state. And as I say in the article: **use with caution!** :)

Answer (score 2):

Chris's answer is correct, but note that *some* of the current database implementations don't actually do much in their `Dispose` calls.

This can mean "poor" but simple code, such as returning a `DataTable` itself, may not actually be much different to "proper" code resource usage-wise.

But because these classes already implement `IDisposable` you *should* always use `Using`, in case their implementation changes in the future to actually dispose something.